# Propensity score variable selection

Tags: propensity-scores

In articles about propensity score it says you should select variables associated with treatment and outcome as covariates to calculate the propensity score. 
What I haven't found explained anywhere is whether this association should be, or at least believed to be, causal or whether it can be a correlation that's not causal.

Example
If ethnicity is known NOT to affect the outcome of interest but is correlated with socioeconomic status which does have an effect on the outcome, should ethnicity be included in the propensity score calculations?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the nature of the correlation.

The propensity score can be used to estimate causal effects, but the requirement is that the set covariates used in estimation of the propensity score represent a sufficient adjustment set so as to satisfy the back door criterion (i.e. satisfy unconfoundedness).

It is fairly straight forward to generate an example in which:

- $V$ is a confounder for the causal effect of $W$ on $Y$,
- Variables $U$ and $V$ are correlated,
- $U$ has no direct effect on $Y$ (i.e. the effect is solely though $V$), and
- Conditioning on $U%$ is insufficient to achieve unconfoundedness

As a DAG, the scenario may look like

[image]